# UK Visa reapplication

Tags: visas, uk

I have made the application for the UK tourist Visa and did not book an appointment for interview/biometrics. I cancelled my application and requested refund.

Now, I want to apply again. They ask, have you ever  applied for the UK Visa before?  I am not sure if I did technically as I didn't give the interview and didn't finish my application (I assume application is completed as I pay for biometrics and  finish the process).

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry about whether you "technically" applied or not. In a visa application, you should almost always err on the side of giving more detail. You should answer "yes" to the question, and you will be given the opportunity to explain your travel history. Here, you should say why you didn't finish the application.

UKVI will already that you are a previous applicant. If you answer "no" to the question, they will wonder what happened with the previous application, and possibly penalise you for omitting information.

Comment: I don’t know if I agree. I will rather say NO and then add an explanation that I started an application previously and withdrew.

Comment: @user56513 Answering yes is more convenient because you will immediately be given a free text box to explain. If you answer no, you will need to add the explanation somewhere else.